# Creating a method that works like ArrayList .add()

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm writing a program that acts as a 'pocket' where the user is able to enter a kind of coin, such as, a quarter and the amount of quarters it has. I was assigned to do 3 different class, the Coin Class in which the coins and their values can be instatiated from, a Pocket Class, where I have to write a method that can add the coins of the user (basically the method would act like ArrayList .add() ) and the PocketClass tester. I have already written most of the code, but I am stuck as to how I could write the following method:

```
 public void addCoin(String s, int i)
     {
          // s is type of coin, you are using s to instantiate a Coin and get value
         // i is number of coins, you are using i to keep adding value to the    totalValue
     }
```

My question is how should I approach this? I am not quite clear on how to create method. Would I use a for-loop in order to keep track of the number of coins? I understand that the addCoin method works a lot like .add() from ArrayList.

Here is the code from my other classes:

```
public class Coin
{
    private final String DOLLAR = "DOLLAR";
    private final String QUARTER = "QUARTER";
    private final String DIME = "DIME";
    private final String NICKEL = "NICKEL";
    private final String PENNY = "PENNY";
    private int value;
    private String coinName;
    public Coin(String s,int count)//name of the coin and also the number of the coins you have 
    {
        //Use if or switch statement to identify incoming string and provide value
       double value=0;
        if(DOLLAR.equalsIgnoreCase(s))
        {
            value=100.0;
        }
        else if(QUARTER.equalsIgnoreCase(s))
        {
            value=25.0;
        }
        else if(DIME.equalsIgnoreCase(s))
        {
            value=10.0;

        }
        else if(NICKEL.equalsIgnoreCase(s))
        {
            value=5.0;
        }
        else if(PENNY.equalsIgnoreCase(s))
        {
            value=1.0;
        }

    }

    public int getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

and how the Pocket class is structured:

```
public class Pocket
{
   private int currentValue; 
   private int totalValue; 
   private Coin quarter;
   private Coin dime;
   private Coin nickle;
   private Coin penny;


   public Pocket()
   {  //Set initial value to zero
      totalValue = 0;
      currentValue = 0;
   }
   public void addCoin(String s, int i)
   {
       // s is type of coin, you are using s to instantiate a Coin and get value
      // i is number of coins, you are using i to keep adding value to the totalValue




   }
   public int getValue()
   {
       return totalValue;
    }
   public void printTotal()
   {
    //print out two different output

   }
}
```

Comment: `I have already written most of the code` would you mind sharing that?

Comment: Could you use a map, with the coin types as keys and the number as value? When someone adds coins just add that number to the value of the corresponding key

Comment: @Neil Locketz And I did not think about using a map. I will look at how that works. Thank you

Comment: Before you start implementing the addCoin method there are some things that I would like to point out. a) In your coin constructor `public Coin(String s,int count)` you are passing in the `count` but that value is not used. b) Calling the class `Coin` in singular form and passing a `count` does not seem right to me either. c) You are not using `    private String coinName;` field either

Comment: @Can'tTell I forgot I had coinName there. I am not using it. And I see, instead of using value, should I set the count as the value?

Comment: That depends on what you want to achieve in the end. Do you want to add several coins to the pocket and get the total value? Are you free to implement as you want or are some of things (like the Constructor) given to you?

Comment: @Can'tTell I would like to add several coins to the pocket and then get the total value.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're adding the `addCoin` method in the `Pocket` class.

If you intend to keep track of the number of coins of each type within a `Pocket`, the simplest way to do so would be to declare a Hashmap that is keyed by the coin type (say, a "quarter" or a "dollar") and valued by the number of coins of that type. An invocation of the `addCoin(type, count)` method, say `addCoin("dollar", 5)` can then check if the hashmap already contains a key named "dollar" and if present, increment it's value by `count`.

Comment: I am new to learning java. And I'm not quite sure what a Hashmap is, but I will look that up. Thank you.

Comment: A hashmap (more specifically, a map) is a collection of key-value pairs. Try reading http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest storing coins in a list so that you can add unlimited number of them.

Example:

```
class Coin{
  //Same as your code....

  public Coin(String coinType){
  //..Same as your code, but removed number of coins
  }
}
```

public class Pocket
   {
     private int currentValue; 
     private int totalValue;
     //Create a list of coins to store unlimited number of coins
     // A pocket can half 5 dimes
     List coins;

```
 public Pocket(){  
    //Set initial value to zero
    totalValue = 0;
    currentValue = 0;
    coins = new ArrayList<Coin>();
 }
 /**
  * This method will take only one coin at a time
  **/
 public void addCoin(String s){
   Coin c = new Coin(s);
   coins.add(c);
   totalValue+=c.getValue();
 }
 /**
  * This method will take any number of coins of same type
  **/
 public void addCoin(String s, int c){
   //Add each one to array
   for(int i=0;i<c;i++)[
      addCoin(s);
   }
 }
}
```

I am not in favor of keeping multiple coin values in one Coin object because of the fact it is not a true representation of an object. What does that mean is tomorrow if you want to store other Coin attributes like "Printed Year", "President Picture on the coin" etc, you will have hard time. In my opinion it is better to represent one real world object (one coin here) using one object instance in the program,

Comment: I also thought of it that way. And I did write something similar to that, passing only one coin at a time. But the assignment calls for a method that enables you to put the amount of coins that you have of a certain type, keep track of them and then add them to get the total value. Thank you for your help and time as well. I totally understand your logic because I thought of that too.

Comment: My code allow that also. See the second overriding method to allow multiple coin at a time.

Comment: Oh I overlooked that part. Thank you. I will try your method but I'm also experimenting a little bit with hashmap. Again thank you for your time.